# Laravel validation: simple way to compare input with selected results from DB

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is there a simple way to use laravel `in` validator to check against selected ids from DB, simple way rather than do the following:

```
public function rules()
{
    // Select all languages ids
    $languges_arr = Language::select('id')->get()->toArray();

    // Map array
    $languges_arr = array_map(function ($object) { return $object['id']; }, $languges_arr);

    // Convert to string        
    $languges_string = implode(', ', $languges_arr);

    // Validation        
    return [
        'language' => 'in:'.$languges_string,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists) validation rule.

```
return [
    'language' => 'exists:languages,id',
];
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `exists` consider scope?

Comment: @mwafi You could achieve that using a [Rule Object](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#using-rule-objects)

Comment: Yep, if you look at the docs, there's an example showing you how to add your own where/scope clauses.